# codelite clang separate options

Tags: c++, ide, code-completion, codelite

I did follow the suggestions on [the documentation to enable clang code completion](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ClangIntegration35), but it seems that on the most recent version there is no option to add search paths and compiler flags separately, I tried adding compiler flags on the search path window, but is not showing any evidence that it caught the new paths:[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the paths separately for clang code completion to work.
You just need to re-build (i.e. clean follow by build) your project once.

If everything is done properly, you should see in CodeLite's build log lines similar to:

`codelite-cc g++ ...` (or `codelite-cc clang++...`)
The `codelite-cc` utility will collect the search paths (and macros and other flags) passed to the compiler and will pass them back to CodeLite, so it will pass it to libClang for getting the proper code completion for your code.

Comment: it seems to be working now, but **only** producing completion hints for includes in the '$(shell pkg-config --cflags boost-1.52)' line. The source inside the project itself is being completely ignored

Comment: When you compile your project, do you see `codelite-cc` in the compiler line? that's the key question here

Comment: When you fail to get input from clang, do you get anything in the 'Clang' tab? (usually there will be an error message there)

Comment: it says 'clang: parsing file <file.cpp>...done'. In some translation units the clang seems to work correctly, and in some others it simply doesn't, the <file.cpp> displays the correct source file, but it doesn't show any error messages. I have both "enable clang" and "inline errors" checkboxes enabled on the clang tab

Comment: You might want to enable CodeLite log: `Settings->Global Editor Preferences->Misc->Log` and set the log verbo to DEBUG. The log is located under `~/.codelite/codelite.log` this should shed some light on what is going on under the hood